# Horizon dashboard not run

Tags: juju, openstack

I've a question for you, after to deploy all service via Juju to realize a Cloud infrastructure using Openstack, I can not open the Horizon Dashboard.
In Juju-gui (http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=szel4n&s=8#.VAHbuWCSxNw) everything relations are in green status.
But if I try to open https://X.X.X.X/horizon the page is white.

thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've exposed the openstack-dashboard service from the juju gui. Also, check the apache logs on the machine horizon is running (e.g. you can use `juju ssh openstack-dashboard/0` to connect to the machine using the juju CLI client).

Comment: I've already exposed it but nothing. While for the apache log /var/log/apache2/error.log  I see just these http://paste.ubuntu.com/8615952/

Comment: I've also try to reinstall that using this guide http://marcoceppi.com/2014/06/deploying-openstack-with-just-two-machines/ but I received the same error